# Why can't I answer my own question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[My question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13367/theory-of-complex-spectra-applying-slater-condon-rules) is open and has a bounty. Nobody has attempted to answer it at the time of writing. I'm unable to answer it as it stands. Below you'll find a screenshot as I see it on mac os using the latest stable version of firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I see what's going on: you have to click the "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom. The site puts in that extra hurdle when you're viewing your own question because otherwise, new users tend to post comments or edits as answers to their questions.